# $\forall$ At the beginning or at the end?

Tags: logic, notation, predicate-logic

I have a set of real numbers $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$ and two functions $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $g:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

What are the differences between the following statements?

1. $\forall v \in \{1, \ldots, n\} ~f(x_v) = 0 \vee g(x_v) = 0$
2. $f(x_v) = 0 \vee g(x_v) = 0 ~\forall v \in \{1, \ldots, n\} ~$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The second one is simply wrong, that's not how things should be written.

It's unambiguous here because there is only one quantifier, but if had been something like $\exists yP(x,y)\forall x$ you wouldn't know whether $\forall x\exists yP(x,y)$ or $\exists y\forall xP(x,y)$ was meant. In my experience, the second option is what's usually meant. But I've seen it mean the first one too.

I reiterate, the second one is wrong, the fact that it's not really ambiguous (in some sense), doesn't make it right.

I *personally* find it acceptable to put quantifiers in the end only if you're mixing natural language with mathematical symbols. For example, "$\exists yP(x,y)$ for all $x$" is of the form "$Q(x)$ for all $x$" which should be translated to "$\forall xQ(x)$", that is, "$\forall x\exists yP(x,y)$".
What's the difference between this and the second (candidate) statement in the question? I didn't use '$\forall$', I actually wrote "for all".

Comment: Comment, down voter?

Comment: I don't agree with your strongly worded answer since I do not see any ambiguity in OP's statements.

Comment: @hot_queen As I explained, when you generalize the OP's statement to statements with more than one variable, there are problems. Obviously, since we are human, we can understand what the second 'statement' means, but that's just it, it's a process of the typical human cognition. Furthermore, in any mathematical logic book, formulas are built with quantifiers behind the condition, not after. I repeat, it's obvious to understand what the second formula means, but when it comes down to it, it's not even a statement (ill formed) and you can't generalize it to statements with two or more variables.

Answer (score 3):

Translate the two statements into English:

1. For all v, either $f(x_v) = 0$ or $g(x_v) = 0$.
2. Either $f(x_v) = 0$ or $g(x_v) = 0$, for all v.

The two statements are **equivalent**. The difference is that the emphasis that this is is true for all $v$ in the set $\{1,\dots,n\}$ has been moved.